# Using Backstack with Fragments In Activity that has a parent

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have `Fragment A`, `Fragment B`. A calls B and adds B to backStack. A is always the first to show up in that `Activity` and the `Activity` is a child of another `Activity` and I want to be able to use the `UpNavigationIcon` to `pop` B from `BackStack` and on second press close `finish()` the `Activity`. This is what I did, but it's not working

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() <= 0){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try popBackStackImmediate()

Comment: Use NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); instead of onBackPressed()